# how to play .opus audio file in android?

Tags: android, audio, android-mediarecorder, opus, google-cloud-speech

I'm developing an app for Recognize speech using google cloud speech APi and recording audio simultaneously. [git link](https://github.com/rowntreerob/Google-speech-Opus-Recorder) 
I tried to play recorded .opus audio file getting IOException 
 `W/System.err: java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.`

Any idea?? Thanks!!

Answer (score 7):

A user on the android stack exchange mentioned being able to [play opus files when they have a .ogg extension](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/126179) in newer versions of Android.

Rename your .opus files to .ogg.

Comment: That's true. I can play with the App "Play Music" opus-encoded files with ending ".ogg".

Comment: This was the answer that worked for me on my *Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge*. I keep it as a portable audio player though I currently have an S22

Comment: @EricHepperle-CodeSlayer2010 you can play by Musicolet Music Player at least if you use its own decoder.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about that specific error, but the [Supported Media Formats page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html) says Opus is only supported in Android 5.0+, and then only in the matroska container.

Make sure you're testing on newer Android, and you may need to demux manually to feed raw packets to the decoder.

If you need Opus support everywhere you can include the C library in your app and call it directly over JNI.

Answer (score 0):

Android 10 and newer can play ".opus" files as such.