# Can't play .opus files with MediaPlayer in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer, opus

I was trying to create a simply MediaPlayer but when playing .opus files it is not working. I tested it with an mp3 and it worked (but does not renaming the opus to mp3, for example). I've read something about .mkv (Matroska Container Format) but I don't know what exactly is it and if it could help me.

In my code I've something like this:

```
var player : MediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
var uri : Uri = Uri.parse(selectedFile.absolutePath)

    try {
        player.setDataSource(selectedFile.absolutePath)
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, uri)
        player.prepare()
        player.start()
    }catch (e : Exception){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error reading file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

And I got different errors trying to solve it, but this is the one I have now (exactly in the MediaPlayer.create line):

> 03-07 02:00:24.393 32251-32251/com.package.app E/MediaPlayer-JNI:
>   QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present 03-07 02:00:24.393
>   32251-32251/com.package.app D/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on
>   client side, trying server side 03-07 02:00:24.413
>   32251-32274/com.package.app E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
>   03-07 02:00:24.413 32251-32251/com.package.app D/MediaPlayer: create
>   failed:
>       java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
>           at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method)
>           at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayer.java:1157)
>           at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:890)
>           at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:863)
>           at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:842)
>           at com.package.app.MainActivity.initializePlayer(MainActivity.kt:167)
>           at com.package.app.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:111)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4791)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19903)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5304)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707) 03-07
>   02:00:24.433 32251-32251/com.package.app E/MediaPlayer: Attempt to
>   call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer
>       error (-38, 0) 03-07 02:00:24.433 32251-32251/com.package.app I/ViewRootImpl: CPU Rendering VSync enable = true 03-07 02:00:24.443
>   32251-32251/com.package.app E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to play .opus audio file in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44435259/how-to-play-opus-audio-file-in-android)

Comment: Renaming to any other format such as is suggested there was useless for me

Comment: Is the android version correct?

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc the MediaPlayer class does not support .opus files

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats

The indication in there saids that can play dot mkv files using the opus codec. Dot mkv files are another types of files, another extension.

Further more, mkv files are only supported on the 5 or later OS.